# Cannot download videos from youtube or vimeo from my android application

Tags: android, youtube

I am developing an android application, I want to download a video from youtube and play it in video view of my application. If it is possible? if I download videos from open source URI of the internet, it worked but from youtube, it shows can't play this video error. please give me a solution.

Comment: If you just want to play it on the device then you can use their API's https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/ and https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries.

Comment: 1 wants to play the video in my custom view. so there is any method to download the videos?